# How to extract certain data from multiple identical indexes and create new column and save it on the first row of the index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12rr2.png)

So i have dataset of movie name, date , revenue accumulated
As you see, there are multiple rows for same movie and revenue is accumulated.
I want to make extract the last revenue accumulated value from a movie name column and make a new column and add that extracted value to the first row of a certain movie. I know how to make new column, but i dont know how would i extract data and add that data to the FIRST ROW of a certain movie. Im using python and pandas

`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`
`df = df.sort_values('Date')`
`df.groupby('Movie name')['Revenue accumulated'].last()`

I now know how to collect the last revenue accumulated of a certain movie using groupby,but i still do not know how to use insert that information to first row of each movie in a new column

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So if you see the pic, the are multiple rows for same movie and there is a column which shows the accumulated revenue. For example, i wanna know how to extract last revenue of movie 'a', last revenue of movie 'b'.. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df.groupby('Movie name')['Revenue accumulated'].last()
```

Comment: is there anyway to do it without changing the order?

Comment: @Godseph `sort=False` ? `df.groupby('Movie name',sort=False)['Revenue accumulated'].last()`

Comment: How would i add that value to a new column. For example, the last revenue accumulated value of movie 'a' to be placed into the first row of movie 'a' with a new column named "Last_revenue"

Comment: What should be placed in the other rows?

Comment: Nothing, just blank space